# Reporting Services 2012 - ReportViewer

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

I have just installed the new SQL Server 2012 with Reporting Services. When I go to my report server page at http://localhost/Reports and select a report, the filter/input bar connected to the report has got a new blueish look. However, when im using the ReportViewer server control version 11.0.0.0, I still get the old beige look as previous versions. It is also missing the new button "Export to Data feed".

Does anyone know if the new ReportViewer server control should look like this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ReportViewer control is actually an ASP.NET control provided with Visual Studio, not part of your SQL Server installation. [ReportViewer on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153697%28v=sql.110%29.aspx)

My suggestion would be to try [installing the Visual Studio 11 beta](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us) and see if there's an updated version of the control in there.

Comment: The control was actually included (version 11.0.0.0) in the VS2011 Beta. Thanks!

Comment: I also use v11.0.0.0 in VS2012 but I get they beige/gray stuff too, and no Feed Export. Do you have any idea? :/

Answer (score 2):

The ReportViewer 2012 standalone package is now released. You may want to review my tip: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvindsh/archive/2012/12/11/microsoft-report-viewer-2012-update-a-gotcha-to-be-aware-of.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is, or at least most of it is. I can't seem to find the Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common dll in my install of VS2012, but that might just be my install. If you don't trying an out of date version from the VS2012 preview, you can download it here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27230